# How to specify a key that contains spaces in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example, how can I access the `last name` of Person?

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    "last name": string;
}

const p: Person;
p."last name"       // ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as JavaScript in this respect; use bracket notation:

```
p["last name"] = "Smith";
```

Comment: Oh, how stupid I am. I remember that you cannot assess properties through bracket notation in some older versions, right?

Comment: I don't think so, as TypeScript is really a superset of JavaScript. So anything fundamental like that is supported.

Comment: I mean, typescript cannot typecheck brackets properly in the old days

Comment: Right, that might be true.